# SQL WHERE clause - best way to display data from every 3 years

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to find the best way to display a list of employees by hire year in intervals of every 3 years (calculated from the year that the report/query was executed).  For example, if 2021 is the report execution year, then it would only show employees hired in the years of 2012, 2015, 2018, etc

The WHERE clause below works, but it's clunky and I'm sure there's a better way to increment the years without using a long list of OR statements that add -6, -9, etc

```
WHERE
  (EmployeesTable.[Hire Year] = @ExecutionYear -3)
  OR 
  (EmployeesTable.[Hire Year] = @ExecutionYear -6)
  OR
  (EmployeesTable.[Hire Year] = @ExecutionYear -9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
WHERE @ExecutionYear - EmployeesTable.[Hire Year] IN (3,6,9)
```

Comment: When I run the query, it causes a Report Builder pop-up to appear -- 'Define Query Parameters' for ExecutionYear (with Parameter Value at <Null>, Data Type at Auto).  I don't get this when running my original query.  The ExecutionYear parameter is based on the Report Builder/SSRS's "Built-in Field" called Execution Time (created using =Year(Globals!ExecutionTime) expression) instead of the main dataset.  This happens for your suggestion and for Alan Schofield's expression.  Any ideas?

Comment: Correction -- it appears the query/report WILL run for the users with no issues.  The define box just pops up for me when I run it from the query designer.

Comment: Make sure the that the variable is spelled exactly the same as the SSRS parameter name, it is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks anyway - your original answer worked.  The other issue I think I'll take to an SSRS forum.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a modulo?

```
where (EmployeesTable.[Hire Year] - @ExecutionYear) % 3 = 0
```

Comment: When I run the query, it causes a Report Builder pop-up to appear -- 'Define Query Parameters' for ExecutionYear (with Parameter Value at <Null>, Data Type at Auto).  I don't get this when running my original query.  The ExecutionYear parameter is based on the Report Builder/SSRS's "Built-in Field" called Execution Time (created using =Year(Globals!ExecutionTime) expression) instead of the main dataset.  This happens for your suggestion and for Alan Schofield's expression.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any suggestions unfortunately not in a position to test/debug. I ran the above in isolation as a test in SSMS and it gave the expected output but unable to delve into SSRS.

Comment: Thanks anyway - your original answer worked.  The other issue I think I'll take to an SSRS forum.